# How can I properly plot a infinity on a matplotlib scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a series of number, and one of it contains a infinity so I changed it into 1.797693134862315E+308.
however the plot does not show data properly

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import randn
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
fig=plt.figure()
ax2=fig.add_subplot(2,2,2)
ax2.scatter([1,2,3,50],[1,2,3,1.797693134862315E+308])
show()
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is that your data points aren't equally spaced

Comment: try to make some synthetic points between infinity and the point before it

Comment: It's not clear what you want to have at the end.